# Regex to match a phrase that is not inside an <a> tag

Tags: java, html, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some HTML and I need to match a phrase "My Phrase" that is not inside an `<a>` tag.

Phrases that should NOT match:

```
1. <a>My Phrase</a>
2. <a><strong>My Phrase</strong></a>
```

Phrases that SHOULD match:

```
3. <strong>My Phrase</strong>
4. My Phrase
```

My **current solution** uses negative lookahead to find matches that aren't followed by a closing `</a>` tag:

```
My Phrase(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/a)
```

https://regex101.com/r/n1d9KZ/1

As you can see in the example, it works for regular text links (case 1) but breaks for case 2 when there are other tags nested inside the "a" tag.

Does anyone have a negative lookahead regex that works for both?

I can't use negative lookbehind with a regex such as `(?<!<a.*?>.*?)My Phrase(?!.*?<\/a>)` because I get the error `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`. I also would prefer not to parse the HTML and remove all current "a" tags, as I need to keep the HTML intact and replace "My Phrase" with "Another Phrase".

Comment: Libraries such as [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) will take lot of the hassle out of HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not so trivial as it is in fact impossible (only Jeff Dean can) to fully process HTML with RegEx.

Because there could be new lines everywhere, with complex attributes and nesting or just invalidity.

Anyway, in the circumstances of your example (no href, no new lines within and inside tags) you can do something like:

```
result = text.replace(/^.*?(My Phrase).*?$/gm, function($0,$1) { 
    var regEx = new RegExp("(" + $1 + ")");
    return $0.indexOf('<a') >= 0 ? $0 : $0.replace(regEx, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

I just bolded the matches in the example, but you could do many things within the callback: https://jsfiddle.net/8Ls0qbvj/